# vue & vuex module is not installed. Nuxt.js in intellij ide's

Tags: vue.js, pycharm, vuex, nuxt.js

I am developing a Nuxt.js application and have a little problem.
Seems like ide (pycharm in my case) doesn't understand that 'vue' and 'vuex' modules are the part of Nuxt.js bundle. Application is working fine but these warnings bring some mess. Is there any way to get rid of it not installing 'vue' and 'vuex' as dependencies?
[store/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEvKF.png)